# Azure Function - How to Get Memory size Usage

Tags: azure, azure-functions

To calculate the price of an Azure Function in a Consumption Plan, I need to determine the runtime and memory usage.

Obtaining the duration and the number of executions is straightforward,

but how can I measure the memory usage for each execution?

[duration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnHCl.png)

I tried using performanceCounters:

`performanceCounters | where counter in ('Private Bytes')`

But the values do not appear to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Please keep in mind that these values coming from the following code are in **Bytes**.

```
performanceCounters
| where counter in ('Private Bytes')
```

So, you need to convert it into MB

Hope that help!